# On a testing phase, run method before spring context starts (run embedded service before spring context initializes)

Tags: spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I have a spring boot application (spring boot 2.2.6), and I'm trying to prepare an integration tests environment (embedded in the application);
I have a method which initializes an embedded elasticsearch service;

During a testing phase, how can I run that method before Spring Context starts to initialize?
Currently, Spring initializes and it complains that it cannot establish a connection to the elasticsearch embedded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a custom initializer:

```java
static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {

            // initialize...

            TestPropertyValues
                    //here you can add properties to connect...
                    .of("some.property.key=some.property.value")
                    .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }

}
```

and add this initializer to your test class:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = Initializer.class)
```

Answer (score 4):

Available in Spring Boot 2.2.6, and Spring Framework 5.2.5 there's an additional option to add dynamic property

```
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void dynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.application.name", () -> "name");
    }
```

This can be used to set up any sort of dynamic property, and is a replacement for the Initalizer pattern.

A bigger example can be seen on the Spring Blog,

https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6

Which shows this example in combination with Testcontainers to set a dynamic database URL for Neo4J that's running in a docker container,

```
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class ExampleIntegrationTests {

    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4j = new Neo4jContainer<>();

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.neo4j.uri", neo4j::getBoltUrl);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is a fine sollution, however it requires docker for testcontainers - I was looking for a solution without external requirements :) anyway, thanks a lot, now I learnt that there exists `TestContainers`

Comment: Note that the dynamic property sources anything can be provided too them its just a much cleaner way of doing it than the initalizer - testcontainers was just a prime use case